# Mass rename columns postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Is it possible to do a mass rename of all the columns of a certain type in postgresql.  I have a range of tables all with geometry type columns (only 1 per table) with names like "the_geom","geom","SP_GEOMETRY" etc, they all have different names due to using different import tools.

I would like to be able to rename them all to just "the_geom" or "geom".

Comment: What version are you on?

Answer (score 4):

Run this query to generate all DDL statements needed:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(c.relname)
    || ' RENAME column ' || quote_ident(a.attname) || ' TO geom;'
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  a.attnum >= 1
AND    a.atttypid = 'geometry'::regtype::oid
AND    a.attname <> 'geom'
AND    NOT a.attisdropped
AND    n.nspname !~~ 'pg_%'  -- exclude catalog & temp tables, to be sure
-- AND    n.nspname = 'myschema'  -- target specific schema only?
```

Answer (score 2):

Querying the system catalogue and generating the commands is usually the easiest approach. Something like this:

```
select
   'alter table ' || quote_ident(nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(relname)
      || ' rename column ' || quote_ident(attname)
      || ' to ' || quote_ident('xxx')
from pg_attribute
join pg_class on pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
where atttypid = 'geometry'::regtype and (attname ~* 'geom')
      and not attisdropped and attnum > 0 and pg_class.oid >= 16384
```